# How to post to friends link iPhone app on friend's wall on Facebook

Tags: ios

In my application I want to have a FaceBook button that will log onto FaceBook so I can share my application with my friends.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to share it with your facebook friends, ypu can use the third party applications like AddThis.Other wise you can use Graph Api, if u need full control over your facebook fnctions.

Comment: thanks ! But , can you give me a sample code about Gragh Api ?? i need it . 
Ah ! You can give me acc skype or yahoo :) . My acc skype is : son.vu.nitrotechvn :)

Comment: You cant implement that with a piece of code.It is better to go through the documentation Graph Api.(http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)